# R - Logistic Regression with Control Variables

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

I just started to get into R for data analysis (previously I just used SPSS or Excel).

Currently, I am trying to run a logistic regression with one dependent and 5 independent while controlling for 3 variables.

My current attempt is:

```
reg_model <- glm(formula = Dependent ~ Independent1 + Independent2 + Independent3 + Independent4 + Independent5, family = binomial(), data = df)
```

I am not sure how (or where) to insert the 3 control variables into the model because just adding the 3 control variables as independent variables into the model seems wrong to me (or am I wrong here?).

Comment: You can control for covariates by either putting them to the right had side of the formula as independent variables or you can do another linear model beforehand and then work with the residuals. The formula reflects the question you want to answer in particular.

Comment: Do you mean like this:

 `reg_model <- glm(formula = Dependent ~ Independent1 + Independent2 + Independent3 + Independent4 + Independent5 + Control1 + Control2 + Control3, family = binomial(), data = df)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control for potential confounders by adding them as independent variables into the model on the right-hand side of the formula.
Note that the estimate (effect size) of the Graduate Record Exam (GRE) score is lower in the second model after controlling for the grade point average (GPA), which is correlated to GRE:

```r
library(readr)

# gre: Graduate Record Exam scores
# gpa: grade point average
data <- read_csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
#> 
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> cols(
#>   admit = col_double(),
#>   gre = col_double(),
#>   gpa = col_double(),
#>   rank = col_double()
#> )
data
#> # A tibble: 400 x 4
#>    admit   gre   gpa  rank
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     0   380  3.61     3
#>  2     1   660  3.67     3
#>  3     1   800  4        1
#>  4     1   640  3.19     4
#>  5     0   520  2.93     4
#>  6     1   760  3        2
#>  7     1   560  2.98     1
#>  8     0   400  3.08     2
#>  9     1   540  3.39     3
#> 10     0   700  3.92     2
#> # … with 390 more rows

model1 <- glm(admit ~ gre, data = data, family = "binomial")
summary(model1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = admit ~ gre, family = "binomial", data = data)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -1.1623  -0.9052  -0.7547   1.3486   1.9879  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept) -2.901344   0.606038  -4.787 1.69e-06 ***
#> gre          0.003582   0.000986   3.633  0.00028 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 499.98  on 399  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 486.06  on 398  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 490.06
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

# gre and gpa are correlated. Lets's control for them!
cor(data)
#>            admit        gre         gpa        rank
#> admit  1.0000000  0.1844343  0.17821225 -0.24251318
#> gre    0.1844343  1.0000000  0.38426588 -0.12344707
#> gpa    0.1782123  0.3842659  1.00000000 -0.05746077
#> rank  -0.2425132 -0.1234471 -0.05746077  1.00000000


model2 <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa, data = data, family = "binomial")
summary(model2)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = admit ~ gre + gpa, family = "binomial", data = data)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -1.2730  -0.8988  -0.7206   1.3013   2.0620  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept) -4.949378   1.075093  -4.604 4.15e-06 ***
#> gre          0.002691   0.001057   2.544   0.0109 *  
#> gpa          0.754687   0.319586   2.361   0.0182 *  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 499.98  on 399  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 480.34  on 397  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 486.34
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>